# scala mysql connection in a website javafx 2.x application works in IDE not when published online

Tags: mysql, scala, maven, web, javafx

I'm writing an scala and java(fx) application in eclipse, use Netbeans to deploy (create jnpl file), and use Maven to do my dependencies. First I tried the combination Scala and JavaFX, which worked fine. But on a later try it looks like the database connection is not succeeding.

I've got a couple computers in my network dedicated for specific tasks, so the website is not running on the same machine as my MySQL (though the ports are forwarded by my router).

To create the DBconnection I used my external IP, I've even tried running my application in another network, which works great (but only in IDEs, both Eclipse and Netbeans). Though, after creating a web-based application (and corresponding deployment) the application stalls after the submit button (for login) is pushed. Which is where the database connection is called.

I'm completely clueless at the moment, since it doesn't appear to be scala/java/javafx code related, and I can't find anything jnlp related.

Does anybody know whether I have to include anything in de jnlp files that I'm not aware of? I saw something on hibernate, but I'm not using that, I'm using mysql-connection which is one of my packaged jars.
I also noticed popup screens are not run (in progress). Important note: when, after deployment, I run it in my Windows environment, it all works fine, but I deploy it on a linux machine (Ubuntu 8.04-server to be precise).
O_o, I found the problem... It resided in the jnlp_content : 'xx', I only checked the first (about) 100 characters which were the same. Apparently, this contains information, resulting in incorrect references. Netbeans helps deployment, apparently all files need to be redeployed after update, also the reference from jnlp_content, even though it appears the same!

Answer (score 1):

Use the [JavaFX packaging tools](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/jfxpub-deployment.htm) to package your application.  You can [call them from Maven](http://code.google.com/p/willow-browser/source/browse/pom.xml) using Maven's ant runner if you want.  Ensure you [sign](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/packaging.htm#BABJGFBH) all your app jars.

Comment: I thought NetBeans handles all these functions (packaging and signing). I'm sure about signing see bottom. Also, in NetBeans, I've 'checked' the option "request unrestricted access", which seems to work, since I get permission to the harddisk (which I need for creating and ftping of files, these work(ed)). 
Warning: 
The signer certificate will expire within six months.
Enter Passphrase for keystore: Enter key password for nb-jfx: 
Signing JAR: xxx\DatabaseHandler-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to xxx\DatabaseHandler-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar as nb-jfx

Comment: you were right, also the html file, containing the jnlp:content wíll differ on each deployment. I was too stubborn to copy that, apparently.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so if somebody reaches this, bear the following in mind.
When you want to create a JavaFX application and you have already deployed a earlier version before, don't be like me, and replace all files generated (web-files/ libs (previous, non-documented!, mistake) and .html .jnlp .jar) files. Don't manually compare and think 'seems about right', it will cost you dearly (it's not worth trying to seconds, it will costs you in days!)!